# Session is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

An event in my global.asax, calls a method in the class which return an integer. I would like to hold this integer in a session variable in global.asax which later I would like to use in a controller. I tried HttpContext.Current.Session.Add, but it gives "Object reference not set to an instance of object". I am not sure how to resolve this and any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the sample code

```
public void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated(object sender, SecurityTokenValidatedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = new StudentClass.GetStudentID(e.ClaimsPrincipal);
        //Im trying to store this ID in a session
        var ru = GetReturnUrl(Request);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ru))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ru);
        }

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi in which method  u are setting this method ?

Comment: please show me code of global.asax file . You should put it session_start method please try that

Comment: Under WSFederationAuthenticationModule securitytokenvalidated event in global asax file.

Comment: please paste the full code of this file it will be helpful.Also tell me what is the project type ? Asp.net forms/ mvc ?

Comment: I have edited my question above. And I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: i think this method get called before Application_Start / Session_Start method if this is the case u cannot use Session in this event. To test please apply breakpoints on app_start / session_start and the method you want to use . if it get called before both I mentioned then you cannot use it.

Comment: True that the above event gets called before Session_Start. Is there a way I can pass a value from securitytokenvalidated event to a controller?

Comment: can you try to access ClaimsPrincipal.Current property if this is available in app_start?

Comment: let me know if this solve I will post it as answer

Comment: Can you access your claims in StartRequest or any other ASP.NET(MVC) event? There it should't be a problem to use HttpContext.Current ...

Comment: @USK check my answer if it helps plz accept

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this was as mention by me in my comment . You can access ClaimPrincipal object in app_start / session_start event and then stored it .I hope it helps 

public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup


    }
     void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       -- here you can get the StudentID and then store it.
        var t = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
        Session["StudentId"] = "Yash";
    }

}
```